# svg background-size in pixels displaying wrong on Win 10 Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, svg

I've created a svg image:

```
<svg id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 6 6"><style>.st0{opacity:.4;fill:#61ffb0;enable-background:new}</style><path class="st0" d="M0 0h1v1H0z"/></svg>
```

I've then used it as a background of a div:

```
.dotted_bg_dark {
    background-image: url(img/pattern-green.svg);
    background-size: 6px;
}

.darkbg {
    background-color: #212734;
    color: #fff;
}

<div class="darkbg dotted_bg_dark" style="height:500px;">Hello World</div>
```

This is displayed correctly (Google Chrome on MacOS):

[image: MacOS screenshot]

However, on Google Chrome on Windows 10 does this (note the diagonal scan line):

[image]

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your .svg file, find the  tag at the beginning and add the following property inside it:

```
preserveAspectRatio="none"
```

[Source][http://www.yootheme.com/support/question/6801?order=modified]